# How to create a checkbox into a confirm dialog using only jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, dialog

I wonder if there is a way to create some checkboxes into a dialog (such as confirm or alert) with no intervention of HTML code, I mean, create a dialog with YES and NO buttons and checkboxes only with Javascript, which appears clicking a link.

Thanks.

Example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VnOW.png

**EDIT**

The result would show:

- a dialog with buttons (OK, CANCEL), and various checkboxes
- user cannot select more than 5 checkboxes, but at least one
- once user select options and click OK, will send text strings corresponding to checkboxes selected. Example: "check1|check4|check7".

Comment: you cannot have checkbox in browser alert box.. though you can use popop like jquery dialog ....search for it

Comment: I already searched in google, but with no good results
Where do I must to search?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using an external library such as Jquery UI or even Twitter Bootstrap. You can create a modal dialog and embed every input type you want in it. Take a look to the JQuery UI docs, it might help. http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: It could be possible if you generate the HTML markup from JavaScript. Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286456/how-to-create-a-dialog-using-jquery-ui-without-html-div-specified